# A component for page flipping when viewing a PDF in .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf-viewer

I have developed an ASP.NET web application which will generate report pack for various customers. We will convert them to PDFs.

Our requirement is to provide viewing of PDF document in the website itself with flipping effect. For a sample please click the below link.

http://viewer.zmags.com/showmag.php?magid=174428#/page18/

How can I achieve this effect in ASP.NET?

Are there any components (in the form of DLLS) available that can be integrated to .NET to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect using WPF or Silverlight component in your web application.